# i want to send json to my API and recive the Json form of response but it show 400 bad request

Tags: android, json, httprequest, httpresponse, protocol-buffers

I and Using google protobuffer to form my json and send as post call to the server but it will return me 400 Bad Request but at a same json i will send to the Postman it will return me valid response but in android it not send me valid response i did not figure out what the actual problem is occurring

```
{
  "worker": {
    "dbInfo": {
      "lifeTime": "ACTIVE"
    },
    "name": {
      "firstName": "abc",
      "lastName": "xyz"
    },
    "contactDetails": {
      "email": {
        "localPart": "abc",
        "domain": "gmail.com"
      },
      "primaryMobile": {
        "code": "ISD_91",
        "number": "117"
      },
      "secondryMobile": [
        {
          "code": "ISD_91",
          "number": "117"
        }
      ]
    },
    "type": {
      "personType": "WORKER"
    },
    "device": {
      "macId": "19:68:15:c4:77:ad",
      "osType": "ANDROID",
      "model": "NOKIA",
      "deviceName": "H@cker"
    }
  },
  "password": "new"
}
```

this is my Json Which is send to POST call to the server in Code i get Json From RegistrationRequestPb

Client Service class

```
public Registration.RegistrationResponsePb getCall(Registration.RegistrationRequestPb request, Class<Registration.RegistrationResponsePb> clazz, Context context, int method) {
        HttpCaller caller = new HttpCaller();
        try {
            return ProtoJsonUtil.fromJson(caller.doCall(request,clazz, UrlPathProvider.UrlPathEnum.REGISTRATION_WORKER,context, RequestMethodEnumAndFormatter.getmethod(RequestMethodEnumAndFormatter.RequestMethodEnum.POST)),clazz);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

HttpCaller

```
Preconditions.checkArgument(messageOrBuilder != null, messageOrBuilder);
        try {
            ReqJSON = ProtoJsonUtil.toJson(messageOrBuilder).replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n| ", "");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        URL = m_serverManeger.getServerUrl(data);
        OptimusHTTP client = new OptimusHTTP(context);
        client.enableDebugging();
        ArrayMap<String, String> params = new ArrayMap<>();
        params.put("query", ReqJSON);
        client.setMethod(method);
        client.setMode(OptimusHTTP.MODE_SEQ);
        client.setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000);
        client.setReadTimeout(10 * 1000);
        client.makeRequest(URL, params, new OptimusHTTP.ResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(String msg) {
                Log.e("resperror", msg);
            }


            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String msg) {
                Log.e("respsucc", msg);
                response = msg;
            }
        });
        return response;
    }
```

OtimusHttp

```
public interface ResponseListener {

        /**
         * On failure.
         *
         * @param msg the msg
         */
        void onFailure(String msg);

        /**
         * On success.
         *
         * @param msg the msg
         */
        void onSuccess(String msg);
    }

    /**
     * The constant METHOD_GET.
     */
    public final static int METHOD_GET = 0;

    /**
     * The constant METHOD_POST.
     */
    public final static int METHOD_POST = 1;

    /**
     * The constant METHOD_PUT.
     */
    public final static int METHOD_PUT = 100;

    /**
     * The constant METHOD_DELETE.
     */
    public final static int METHOD_DELETE = 101;

    /**
     * The constant CONTENT_TYPE_FORM_URL_ENCODED.
     */
    public final static String CONTENT_TYPE_FORM_URL_ENCODED = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    /**
     * The constant CONTENT_TYPE_JSON.
     */
    public final static String CONTENT_TYPE_JSON = "application/json";

    /**
     * The constant CONTENT_TYPE_PDF.
     */
    public final static String CONTENT_TYPE_PDF = "application/pdf";

    /**
     * The constant CONTENT_TYPE_HTML.
     */
    public final static String CONTENT_TYPE_HTML = "text/html";

    /**
     * The constant CONTENT_TYPE_IMG_PNG.
     */
    public final static String CONTENT_TYPE_IMG_PNG = "image/png";

    /**
     * The constant CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT.
     */
    public final static String CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT = "text/plain";

    /**
     * The constant MODE_SEQ.
     */
    public final static int MODE_SEQ = 2;

    /**
     * The constant MODE_PARALLEL.
     */
    public final static int MODE_PARALLEL = 3;

    private boolean DEBUG = false;

    //LOGTAG
    private final String LOGTAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    private int connectTimeout = 10 * 1000; //10s

    private String contentType = CONTENT_TYPE_JSON;

    private Context context;

    private ArrayMap<String, String> headerMap = new ArrayMap<>();

    private int method;

    private int mode;

    private int readTimeout = 10 * 1000; //10s

    /**
     * Instantiates a new Optimus http.
     *
     * @param context the context
     */
    public OptimusHTTP(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        setMode(MODE_SEQ);
        setMethod(METHOD_GET);
    }

    /**
     * Cancel req.
     *
     * @param req the req
     */
    public void cancelReq(HttpReq req) {
        if (req != null && (req.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING
                || req.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING)) {
            req.cancel(true);
            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.d(LOGTAG, "*---------------------- Request Cancelled ----------------*");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Enable debugging.
     */
    public void enableDebugging() {
        DEBUG = true;
    }

    /**
     * Gets connect timeout.
     *
     * @return the connect timeout
     */
    public int getConnectTimeout() {
        return connectTimeout;
    }

    /**
     * Sets connect timeout.
     *
     * @param timeInMs the time in ms
     */
    public void setConnectTimeout(int timeInMs) {
        this.connectTimeout = timeInMs;
    }

    /**
     * Gets content type.
     *
     * @return the content type
     */
    public String getContentType() {
        return contentType;
    }

    /**
     * Sets content type.
     *
     * @param contentType the content type
     */
    public void setContentType(String contentType) {
        this.contentType = contentType;
    }

    /**
     * Gets method.
     *
     * @return the method
     */
    public int getMethod() {
        return method;
    }

    /**
     * Sets method.
     *
     * @param method the method
     */
    public void setMethod(int method) {
        this.method = method;
    }

    /**
     * Gets mode.
     *
     * @return the mode
     */
    public int getMode() {
        return mode;
    }

    /**
     * Sets mode.
     *
     * @param mode the mode
     */
    public void setMode(int mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    /**
     * Gets read timeout.
     *
     * @return the read timeout
     */
    public int getReadTimeout() {
        return readTimeout;
    }

    /**
     * Sets read timeout.
     *
     * @param timeInMs the time in ms
     */
    public void setReadTimeout(int timeInMs) {
        this.readTimeout = timeInMs;
    }

    /**
     * Make the Request
     *
     * @param url      the url
     * @param params   the params
     * @param listener the listener
     * @return HttpReq reference if a request is made null if no request is made
     */
    public HttpReq makeRequest(String url, ArrayMap<String, String> params,
                               ResponseListener listener) {
        HttpReq req = new HttpReq(connectTimeout, readTimeout, contentType, headerMap);
        HttpReqPkg pkg = new HttpReqPkg();
        if (method == METHOD_GET) {
            pkg.setMethod("GET");
            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.e(LOGTAG, "*---------------------- GET Request ----------------------*");
            }
        } else if (method == METHOD_POST) {
            pkg.setMethod("POST");
            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.e(LOGTAG, "*---------------------- POST Request ----------------------*");
            }
        } else if (method == METHOD_PUT) {
            pkg.setMethod("PUT");
            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.e(LOGTAG, "*---------------------- PUT Request ----------------------*");
            }
        } else if (method == METHOD_DELETE) {
            pkg.setMethod("DELETE");
            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.e(LOGTAG, "*---------------------- DELETE Request ----------------------*");
            }
        }
        Log.e("Url",url);
        pkg.setUri(url);
        pkg.setParams(params);

        if (isOnline()) {
            if (mode == MODE_SEQ) {
                SeqAsyncTask(req, pkg, listener);
            } else if (mode == MODE_PARALLEL) {
                ParallelAsyncTask(req, pkg, listener);
            }
            return req;
        } else {
            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.d(LOGTAG, "Not connected to Internet ! OptimusHTTP didn't make a request!");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setHeaderMap(ArrayMap<String, String> headerMap) {
        this.headerMap = headerMap;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void ParallelAsyncTask(HttpReq req, HttpReqPkg p, ResponseListener listener) {
        req.setOnResultsListener(listener);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            req.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, p);
        } else {
            req.execute(p);
        }
    }

    private void SeqAsyncTask(HttpReq req, HttpReqPkg p, ResponseListener listener) {
        req.setOnResultsListener(listener);
        req.execute(p);
    }

    private boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (cm != null) {
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

HttpReq

```
private int connectTimeout;

    private String contentType;

    private ArrayMap<String, String> headerMap = new ArrayMap<>();

    private OptimusHTTP.ResponseListener listener;

    private int readTimeout;

    private int resCode;

    private String resMsg;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new Http req.
     *
     * @param connectTimeout the connect timeout
     * @param readTimeout    the read timeout
     * @param contentType    the content type
     */
    public HttpReq(int connectTimeout, int readTimeout, String contentType,
                   ArrayMap<String, String> headerMap) {
        resCode = 0;
        resMsg = "na";
        this.connectTimeout = connectTimeout;
        this.readTimeout = readTimeout;
        this.contentType = contentType;

        this.headerMap = headerMap;
    }

    /**
     * Sets on results listener.
     *
     * @param listener the listener
     */
    public void setOnResultsListener(OptimusHTTP.ResponseListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(HttpReqPkg... params) {

        URL url;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        String username = params[0].getUsername();
        String password = params[0].getPassword();
        String authStringEnc = null;

        if (username != null && password != null) {
            String authString = username + ":" + password;

            byte[] authEncBytes;
            authEncBytes = Base64.encode(authString.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
        }

        String uri = params[0].getUri();

        if (params[0].getMethod().equals("GET") && params[0].getParams().size()>0) {
            uri += "?" + params[0].getEncodedParams();
        }

        try {
            StringBuilder sb;
            // create the HttpURLConnection
            Log.e("url",uri);
            url = new URL(uri);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            if (authStringEnc != null) {
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
            }

            if (params[0].getMethod().equals("POST")
                    || params[0].getMethod().equals("PUT")
                    || params[0].getMethod().equals("DELETE")) {
                // enable writing output to this url
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
            }

            switch (params[0].getMethod()) {
                case "POST":
                    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    break;
                case "GET":
                    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    break;
                case "PUT":
                    connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
                    break;
                case "DELETE":
                    connection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
                    break;
            }

            // give it x seconds to respond
            connection.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
            connection.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");

            for (int i = 0; i < headerMap.size(); i++) {
                connection.setRequestProperty(headerMap.keyAt(i), headerMap.valueAt(i));
            }

            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                    "" + params[0].getEncodedParams().getBytes().length);

            connection.connect();
            if (params[0].getMethod().equals("POST") || params[0].getMethod().equals("PUT")) {
                OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                writer.write(params[0].getEncodedParams());
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            }

            // read the output from the server
            InputStream in;
            resCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            resMsg = connection.getResponseMessage();
            if (resCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                in = connection.getErrorStream();
            } else {
                in = connection.getInputStream();
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            sb.append(resCode).append(" : ").append(resMsg);
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            listener.onFailure(Integer.toString(resCode) + " : " + resMsg);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // close the reader; this can throw an exception too, so
            // wrap it in another try/catch block.
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (listener != null && result != null) {
            listener.onSuccess(result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        disableConnectionReuseIfNecessary();
    }

    private void disableConnectionReuseIfNecessary() {
        // Work around pre-Froyo bugs in HTTP connection reuse.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
            System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        }
    }
```

HttpPkgReq

```
private String method = "GET";

    private Map<String, String> params = new ArrayMap<>();

    private String password = null;

    private String uri;

    private String username = null;

    /**
     * Gets encoded params.
     *
     * @return the encoded params
     */
    public String getEncodedParams() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String value = null;
        if(params.size()>0) {
            for (String key : params.keySet()) {
                try {
                    value = URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key), "UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (sb.length() > 0) {
                    sb.append("&");
                }
                if(getMethod().equals("GET")) {
                    sb.append(key).append("=").append(value);
                }else{
                    sb.append(value);
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Gets method.
     *
     * @return the method
     */
    public String getMethod() {
        return method;
    }

    /**
     * Sets method.
     *
     * @param method the method
     */
    public void setMethod(String method) {
        this.method = method;
    }

    /**
     * Gets params.
     *
     * @return the params
     */
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }

    /**
     * Sets params.
     *
     * @param params the params
     */
    public void setParams(Map<String, String> params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    /**
     * Gets uri.
     *
     * @return the uri
     */
    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    /**
     * Sets uri.
     *
     * @param uri the uri
     */
    public void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    /**
     * Gets username.
     *
     * @return the username
     */
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    /**
     * Sets username.
     *
     * @param username the username
     */
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    /**
     * Sets param.
     *
     * @param key   the key
     * @param value the value
     */
    public void setParam(String key, String value) {
        params.put(key, value);
    }

    /**
     * Gets password.
     *
     * @return the password
     */
    String getPassword() {
        return uri;
    }

    /**
     * Sets password.
     *
     * @param password the password
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
```

this is my code which i used to send and receive Json but id will send me 400 BAD REQUEST

postman screenshot, it will return 200

[image]

please provide me some solution  of this or send some library so i use them to call for http Request or response using json

this is my response:
from Python Server

{"worker":{"dbInfo":{"id":"ky","lifeTime":"ACTIVE"},"name":{"firstName":"abcd","lastName":"xyz"},"contactDetails":{"email":{"localPart":"abcd","domain":"gmail.com"},"primaryMobile":{"code":"ISD_91","number":"11734"},"secondryMobile":[{"code":"ISD_91","number":"1174"}]},"type":{"personType":"WORKER"},"device":{"macId":"19:68:15:c4:77:ad","osType":"ANDROID","model":"Redmi","deviceName":"H@cker"}},"login":{"dbInfo":{"id":"k4"},"contactDetails":{"email":{"localPart":"abcd","domain":"gmail.com"},"primaryMobile":{"code":"ISD_91","number":"11734"},"secondryMobile":[{"code":"ISD_91","number":"1174"}]},"password":"$2b$12$Wq24XUAyxa6Dyp7RE8ilJ.pYwmRd8uuhvhDWmz6EdEgaY0cFE51TC","personType":{"personType":"WORKER"},"workerRef":{"dbInfo":{"id":"ky"},"name":{"firstName":"abcd","lastName":"xyz"}},"timeCreation":{"date":"16","month":"10","year":"2019","milliseconds":"1571239374500","formattedDate":"2019-10-16 15:22:54","timezone":"IST"}},"status":"SUCCESS"}

Comment: where is the response coming from?  php?

Comment: i am using python server

Comment: u have to call the api. where is the py located?localhost? you have to make an api call to your....api... look up ways to call a python server.

Comment: i am using heroku app for my python webserver i call from postman it will give me proper response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something like this.

```
 public static String executePost() {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        //Create connection
        URL url = new URL("URL_HERE");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString("REQUEST_JSON".getBytes().length));
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        //Send request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes("REQUEST_JSON");
        wr.close();

        //Get Response
        try {
            is = connection.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            if (connection instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
                HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                int statusCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                if (statusCode != 200) {
                    is = httpConn.getErrorStream();
                }
            }
        }

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder(); // or StringBuffer if Java version 5+
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();
        return response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

This will return your response as a string.

Comment: i am using flask for run my python app